# appcompat-v7:27.1.1 conflicts with play-services:11.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, android-support-library

I am working on a new app. Presently I am trying to add dependency.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
```

When I do I get a gradle compile error on implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' saying:

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0

Any ideas how to best resolve this issue?

Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.boulbabazitouni.getdevicelocation_time"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
}
```

Comment: You should update to latest play services and maybe not just import the complete services but just the modules you are using?
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup (read the bluish note section)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you have some transient dependencies in this libraries. Whenever this happens you can explicitly add the conflicting dependencies and match them with your current version:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

Comment: Could not find method iimplementation() for arguments [com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1] on object of type

Comment: there's a typo in "iimplementation"

Comment: im new to android so im just following a tutorial in how to use google services to get location so if you can explain more that would be great 
what i did i deleted : implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' and replaced it with implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: you should keep implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'.

Comment: i will update the question with your modification but its the same thing

Comment: Try updating the gms dependency >  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1

Comment: you're trying to import the complete play services suit, you should import olnly those you're actually are going to use. Which service are you trying to use?

Comment: Im sorry i look to newbie in this. Im trying to locate the device and get the longitude and latitude so which service is that ?

Comment: probably the location api-> replace the play services depndencies with this one- > com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1

Comment: its working fine now i need to add this dependency -> implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

Comment: great :) Glad you found out