# Which com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads version is compatible with com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1?

Tags: android, google-play-services

**No duplicate:**
In my question I've already linked an answer similar to the supposed duplicate and explained, why I'm not looking for such an answer.

Android Studio 3.2.1 automatically included

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

for my new app. I manually included

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

following the [official guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start).

The official guide from google seems to be outdated, as Android Studio immediately suggests using version 17.1.3 instead.

In both cases however there is a red line under appcompat-v7 and a tooltip warning me that:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0.

I do get the general problem here, play-services-ads transitively depends on an old version of some support library. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50565299/1785730) suggests to simply include the offending libraries manually in the correct version.

However, I don't like this solution for two reasons:

1. I simply don't want to deal with problems like this. There should be compatible versions available for the google libraries.
2. At some point in the future I might have forgotten why I included all these libraries I don't even know what they do. I might want to update the appcompat and play-services-ads dependencies without thinking about all this again.

Is version 17.1.3 the most recent version of play-services-ads as of now? Does that mean that play-services-ads is generally lagging behind? If so, I would prefer to downgrade appcompat-v7 instead of including some library versions manually.

What would be the correct version of appcomat-v7 for play-services-ads version 17.1.3? Or maybe more generally asked: Which are the most recent versions of appcompat-v7 and play-services-ads that work together hassle free?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle mixing versions 27.1.1 and 26.1.0 \[Android Studio\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088736/gradle-mixing-versions-27-1-1-and-26-1-0-android-studio)

Comment: like it or not, this is how to deal with conflicting versions - while it tells you that it depends on version `26.1.0` - which is the version you might be looking for; in case you intend to build against the same outdated version.

Comment: Well, I think I made it very clear, that this is not the kind of solution I'm looking for. What about downgrading appcompat-v7?

Comment: And I would appreciate a comment on why play-services-ads doesn't get updated.

Comment: @user1785730,good observation ,I am also face this problem in many times when I work with gradle and google-paly-services ,and try to update till reach for suitable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

26.1.0 is the correct appcompat-v7 version for play-services-ads 17.1.*

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

This also requires `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to be set to 26.